Unity 2D game C# Script issue
my c# script has some problem player can moving and show run, jump,attack animation but when i walk forward player doesn't show run,attack,jump animation .
please help me check the code encountering issues with player animations
look this one
here is my player fallstate:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerFallState : PlayerAirState
{
    public PlayerFallState(Player player, PlayerStateMachine stateMachine, string animationBoolName) : base(player, stateMachine, animationBoolName)
    {
    }

    public override void Enter()
    {
        base.Enter();
    }

    public override void Exit()
    {
        base.Exit();
    }

    public override void Update()
    {
        base.Update();
        if (player.isPLayerGrounded())
            stateMachine.ChangeState(player.idleState);

    }
}


Please dont post code as pictures, read [ask] and [mcve]
